# Static linking of SDL2 and SDL2_ttf

Tags: c, windows, makefile, mingw

I'm writing a package which uses SDL2 and SDL2_ttf,and I'm trying to compile into an executable that does not need any of the .dll files at run time (static linking i guess is the name.). I'm quite new to all of this static vs dynamic linking, and it is a hell of a struggle. Anyways, searching over the internet, I found that I could compile SDL2 as following:

**-Wl,-Bstatic -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lws2_32 -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid -lcomdlg32 -lhid -lsetupapi**

Since I keep all the external libraries in the same folder as my package, I changed above to:

**-Wl,-Bstatic -lmingw32 -L vendor/SDL/lib -l:libSDL2main.a -l:libSDL2.a  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lws2_32 -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid -lcomdlg32 -lhid -lsetupapi**

And it worked !! No .dll files needed ! I was so happy and proud of myself. Then I attempted to include SDL2_ttf as well. In my mind, I only need the libSDL2_ttf.a file and the header file. So I just copied to those files in the right places in my holder and attempted to compile with:

**-Wl,-Bstatic -lmingw32 -L vendor/SDL/lib -l:libSDL2main.a -l:libSDL2.a -l:libSDL2_ttf.a  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lws2_32 -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid -lcomdlg32 -lhid -lsetupapi**

But, I get all this good reference errors:

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: SDL/lib\libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): in function `TTF_initFontMetrics':
/Users/valve/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15-source/foo-x64/../SDL_ttf.c:422: undefined reference to FT_MulFix
....
....

What am I missing here ? Platform target is Windows and I'm using mingw compiler.

Edit:
SDL_ttf has FreeType as a dependency, and FreeType as its own dependecies. What would you do in this case?

Comment: FreeType I guess. It's a font rendering library. And all of its functions start with FT_

Comment: I realized now that FreeType is a dependency...